# I have a dust sensor and I need to take in a voltage from the GPIO pins

Tags: gpio, sensor

I recently got a Dust sensor from a company and it says that the voltage out corresponds to the concentration of dust in the air. How can I use the GPIO pins to get the voltage reading?

The voltage is lower than 4 volts as well.

Comment: You need to put an ADC between the sensor and your Pi, since the Pi does not have analog inputs or outputs.

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: Here is the manual for the sensor: http://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/0/0a/Dust-Sensor-User-Manual-EN.pdf

Comment: You'll need to do a lot more research. Two ADCs that I frequently use are the MCP3008 and ADS1115. You can search the Internet for either one of those, combined with "Raspberry Pi", and optionally with a specific programming language.

Comment: I too searched for the same. Now am trying with ADC MCP3008. Hope it will work.
or try https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/projects/building-raspberry-pi-controllers-part-5-reading-analog-data-with-an-rpi/

Answer (score 1):

Use an ADC (analogue-digital converter) like the MCP3008. Easy to get readings with Python:

```
from gpiozero import MCP3008

dust = MCP3008()

while True:
    print(dust.voltage)
```

You can use `dust.voltage` if you need the voltage itself, or use `dust.value` to get a normalised value (0-1). See the [gpiozero docs](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_spi.html) and this [guide to using ADCs](https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/physical-computing) (including wiring).

Answer (score 0):

I found several tutorials online for connecting analog inputs to a Raspberry Pi. I'd recommend the [Adafruit](https://learn.adafruit.com) site. I noticed that one of the chips they used was about the same price as an small Arduino, which has 5 analog inputs. There are many online tutorials to show you how to communicate between and Arduino and Raspberry Pi.